# MPMoviePlayerViewController gets dismissed, when app resignes active state

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, uiviewcontroller

When I set my iPhone to sleep, switch to another app, etc., and then come back again, a prior visible `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (presented with `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:`) is not there anymore. How can I maintain it, when my app loses the focus?

Answer (score 3):

I found, that the "audio" background-mode has to be specified in the Info.plist-file to achieve the desired behavior. But interestingly my app got rejected after I added this, because it is not allowed when the app doesn't do actual background audio stuff. I think this is called a "dilemma". ;)